# Why is require_once so bad to use?

Tags: php, performance, require-once

Everything I read about better PHP coding practices keeps saying don't use `require_once` because of speed.

Why is this?

What is the proper/better way to do the same thing as `require_once`? If it matters, I'm using PHP 5.

Comment: This question is pretty old now, and the answers are dubiously relevant anymore. It would be great to see an updated set of answers from the participants :)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

`require_once` and `include_once` both require that the system keeps a log of what's already been included/required. Every `*_once` call means checking that log. So there's definitely *some* extra work being done there but  enough to detriment the speed of the whole app?

... I really doubt it... Not unless you're on *really* old hardware or doing it a *lot*.

If you *are* doing thousands of `*_once`, you could do the work yourself in a lighter fashion. For simple apps, just making sure you've only included it once *should* suffice but if you're still getting redefine errors, you could something like this:

```
if (!defined('MyIncludeName')) {
    require('MyIncludeName');
    define('MyIncludeName', 1);
}
```

I'll personally stick with the `*_once` statements but on silly  million-pass benchmark, you can see a difference between the two:

```
                php                  hhvm
if defined      0.18587779998779     0.046600103378296
require_once    1.2219581604004      3.2908599376678
```

10-100× slower with `require_once` and it's curious that `require_once` is seemingly slower in `hhvm`. Again, this is only relevant to your code if you're running `*_once` thousands of times.

---

```
<?php // test.php

$LIMIT = 1000000;

$start = microtime(true);

for ($i=0; $i<$LIMIT; $i++)
    if (!defined('include.php')) {
        require('include.php');
        define('include.php', 1);
    }

$mid = microtime(true);

for ($i=0; $i<$LIMIT; $i++)
    require_once('include.php');

$end = microtime(true);

printf("if defined\t%s\nrequire_once\t%s\n", $mid-$start, $end-$mid);
```

---

```
<?php // include.php

// do nothing.
```

Comment: I doubt your defined() method is any faster than the built-in lookup table, but I agree with your overall point - surely a non-issue?!

Comment: I'm fairly sure you're right Bobby but I'm not advocating the defines over _once. It's just an option. The time it would take to interpret the code might even make it marginally slower but, that said, I don't know how thorough the internal method is. It might do extra work to ensure no duplicates.

Comment: The other downside is APC doesn't cache include_once and require_once calls IIRC

Comment: I just did a very basic test of the two methods -- I did 1,000,000 iterations including a file which simply defined a constant 'testinclude' to true. In the first test, I used require_once, the second I used if(!defined('testinclude')) and the results were interesting:

Require: 0.81639003753662
Not Defined: 0.17906713485718
Defined is 0.63732290267944 microseconds faster.

Comment: The case with define will be faster since you're not performing any kind of extra checks such as using realpath. It's not comparing two things that are truly the same.

Answer (score 147):

This thread makes me cringe, because there's already been a "solution posted", and it's, for all intents and purposes, wrong. Let's enumerate:

1. Defines are **really** expensive in PHP. You can [look it up](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40165) or test it yourself, but the only efficient way of defining a global constant in PHP is via an extension. (Class constants are actually pretty decent performance wise, but this is a moot point, because of 2)
2. If you are using `require_once()` appropriately, that is, for inclusion of classes, you don't even need a define; just check if `class_exists('Classname')`. If the file you are including contains code, i.e. you're using it in the procedural fashion, there is absolutely no reason that `require_once()` should be necessary for you; each time you include the file you presume to be making a subroutine call.

So for a while, a lot of people did use the `class_exists()` method for their inclusions. I don't like it because it's fugly, but they had good reason to: `require_once()` was pretty inefficient before some of the more recent versions of PHP. But that's been fixed, and it is my contention that the extra bytecode you'd have to compile for the conditional, and the extra method call, would by far overweigh any internal hashtable check.

Now, an admission: this stuff is tough to test for, because it accounts for so little of the execution time.

Here is the question you should be thinking about: includes, as a general rule, are expensive in PHP, because every time the interpreter hits one it has to switch back into parse mode, generate the opcodes, and then jump back. If you have a 100+ includes, this will definitely have a performance impact. The reason why using or not using require_once is such an important question is because it makes life difficult for opcode caches. An [explanation for this](http://t3.dotgnu.info/blog/php/demystifying-autofilter.html) can be found here, but what this boils down to is that:

- If during parse time, you know exactly what include files you will need for the entire life of the request, `require()` those at the very beginning and the opcode cache will handle everything else for you.
- If you are not running an opcode cache, you're in a hard place. Inlining all of your includes into one file (don't do this during development, only in production) can certainly help parse time, but it's a pain to do, and also, you need to know exactly what you'll be including during the request.
- Autoload is very convenient, but slow, for the reason that the autoload logic has to be run every time an include is done. In practice, I've found that autoloading several specialized files for one request does not cause too much of a problem, but you should not be autoloading all of the files you will need.
- If you have maybe 10 includes (this is a *very* back of the envelope calculation), all this wanking is not worth it: just optimize your database queries or something.

Comment: This is 4 years old and for the most part no longer applies, `define()`, `require_once()` and `defined()` all take about 1-2 microseconds each on my machine.

Comment: But that's 2 microseconds sooner the user would have the page. Over a year of page views, that could save the user a whole 3 seconds! They could watch one tenth of a commercial in that time! Think of the user. Don't waste microseconds.

Comment: Just so everyone is aware of the sarcasm, a microsecond is 1/1000000 of a second.

Comment: `class_exists('Classname')` checks if a class name has been included while `require_once()` checks that a file has been included, keep in mind that multiple files can contain the same class.

Comment: @AndrewEnsley You are simply mistaken with all your sarcasm.
You are ignorant about the fact that PHP also runs on microprocessors, 1 microsecond on your PC is several milliseconds on a microprocessor.
Now what about having 20 include files, a larger project ?
That's 20 times several milliseconds delay introduced, so we are already reaching a point thats noticeable to a human.
If that script is called frequently it will cause performance issues on the system.

Optimization is not a joke and the whole world is not turning around your PC. There are ten thousands of CPUs in use.

Comment: @John. It was a joke made in good spirits. No malice intended. If it's worth it for you to optimize your includes, go right ahead.

Comment: @AndrewEnsley Just tried to show that the world of PHP is not limited to Ghz computers.
If you run it on a 30MHz cpu all the performance issues sum up.

Comment: @John: 30Mhz? O_O The slowest Raspberry Pi released 5 years ago was 700Mhz. If someone is running PHP on a 30Mhz CPU, they might have chosen the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @AndrewEnsley and raspi is a standard ?:)
But even on a 700MHZ  ARM (note that's by far not the same performance as a 700mhz intel core ) it will make a difference. Especially if you have many includes and many calls. It all sums up.

I've personally had PHP on way slower embedded computers than a current raspi and there are ten thousands of those still in the field. And that's just one product of one company.
It's working well, PHP was not a bad choice.

Answer (score 68):

I got curious and checked out Adam Backstrom's link to [Tech Your Universe](https://web.archive.org/web/20080808221243/http://www.techyouruniverse.com/software/php-performance-tip-require-versus-require_once). This article describes one of the reasons that require should be used instead of require_once. However, their claims didn't hold up to my analysis. I'd be interested in seeing where I may have misanalysed the solution. I used PHP 5.2.0 for comparisons.

I started out by creating 100 header files that used require_once to include another header file. Each of these files looked something like:

```
<?php
    // /home/fbarnes/phpperf/hdr0.php
    require_once "../phpperf/common_hdr.php";

?>
```

I created these using a quick Bash hack:

```
for i in /home/fbarnes/phpperf/hdr{00..99}.php; do
    echo "<?php
    // $i" > $i
    cat helper.php >> $i;
done
```

This way I could easily swap between using require_once and require when including the header files.  I then created an app.php to load the one hundred files.  This looked like:

```
<?php
    // Load all of the php hdrs that were created previously
    for($i=0; $i < 100; $i++)
    {
        require_once "/home/fbarnes/phpperf/hdr$i.php";
    }

    // Read the /proc file system to get some simple stats
    $pid = getmypid();
    $fp = fopen("/proc/$pid/stat", "r");
    $line = fread($fp, 2048);
    $array = split(" ", $line);

    // Write out the statistics; on RedHat 4.5 with kernel 2.6.9
    // 14 is user jiffies; 15 is system jiffies
    $cntr = 0;
    foreach($array as $elem)
    {
        $cntr++;
        echo "stat[$cntr]: $elem\n";
    }
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

I contrasted the require_once headers with require headers that used a header file looking like:

```
<?php
    // /home/fbarnes/phpperf/h/hdr0.php
    if(!defined('CommonHdr'))
    {
        require "../phpperf/common_hdr.php";
        define('CommonHdr', 1);
    }
?>
```

I didn't find much difference when running this with require vs. require_once. In fact, my initial tests seemed to imply that require_once was slightly faster, but I don't necessarily believe that.  I repeated the experiment with 10000 input files. Here I did see a consistent difference. I ran the test multiple times, the results are close but using require_once uses on average 30.8 user jiffies and 72.6 system jiffies; using require uses on average 39.4 user jiffies and 72.0 system jiffies. Therefore, it appears that the load is slightly lower using require_once. However, the wall clock time is slightly increased. The 10,000 require_once calls use 10.15 seconds to complete on average and 10,000 require calls use 9.84 seconds on average.

The next step is to look into these differences. I used [strace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) to analyse the system calls that are being made.

Before opening a file from require_once the following system calls are made:

```
time(NULL)                              = 1223772434
lstat64("/home", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/home/fbarnes", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/home/fbarnes/phpperf", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/home/fbarnes/phpperf/h", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=270336, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/home/fbarnes/phpperf/h/hdr0.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=88, ...}) = 0
time(NULL)                              = 1223772434
open("/home/fbarnes/phpperf/h/hdr0.php", O_RDONLY) = 3
```

This contrasts with require:

```
time(NULL)                              = 1223772905
lstat64("/home", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/home/fbarnes", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/home/fbarnes/phpperf", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/home/fbarnes/phpperf/h", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=270336, ...}) = 0
lstat64("/home/fbarnes/phpperf/h/hdr0.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=146, ...}) = 0
time(NULL)                              = 1223772905
open("/home/fbarnes/phpperf/h/hdr0.php", O_RDONLY) = 3
```

Tech Your Universe implies that require_once should make more lstat64 calls. However, they both make the same number of lstat64 calls.  Possibly, the difference is that I am not running APC to optimize the code above. However, next I compared the output of strace for the entire runs:

```
[fbarnes@myhost phpperf]$ wc -l strace_1000r.out strace_1000ro.out
  190709 strace_1000r.out
  210707 strace_1000ro.out
  401416 total
```

Effectively there are approximately two more system calls per header file when using require_once. One difference is that require_once has an additional call to the time() function:

```
[fbarnes@myhost phpperf]$ grep -c time strace_1000r.out strace_1000ro.out
strace_1000r.out:20009
strace_1000ro.out:30008
```

The other system call is getcwd():

```
[fbarnes@myhost phpperf]$ grep -c getcwd strace_1000r.out strace_1000ro.out
strace_1000r.out:5
strace_1000ro.out:10004
```

This is called because I decided to relative path referenced in the hdrXXX files. If I make this an absolute reference, then the only difference is the additional time(NULL) call made in the code:

```
[fbarnes@myhost phpperf]$ wc -l strace_1000r.out strace_1000ro.out
  190705 strace_1000r.out
  200705 strace_1000ro.out
  391410 total
[fbarnes@myhost phpperf]$ grep -c time strace_1000r.out strace_1000ro.out
strace_1000r.out:20008
strace_1000ro.out:30008
```

This seems to imply that you could reduce the number of system calls by using absolute paths rather than relative paths. The only difference outside of that is the time(NULL) calls which appear to be used for instrumenting the code to compare what is faster.

One other note is that the APC optimization package has an option called "apc.include_once_override" that claims that it reduces the number of system calls made by the require_once and include_once calls (see the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php)).

Comment: And any "optimization" that you have to run 10,000 times to see a such a minuscule difference is not even worthy of worrying about.  Use a profiler and find out where the *real* bottlenecks are in your application.  I doubt this question is the bottleneck.

Comment: What this all means is that it doesn't matter at all. Use whatever works better for you logically.

Comment: wat are jiffies

Answer (score 22):

Can you give us any links to these coding practices which say to avoid it? As far as I'm concerned, **it's a complete non-issue**. I haven't looked at the source code myself, but I'd imagine that the only difference between `include` and `include_once` is that `include_once` adds that filename to an array and checks over the array each time. It'd be easy to keep that array sorted, so searching over it should be O(log n), and even a medium-largish application would only have a couple of dozen includes.

Comment: one is, http://www.chazzuka.com/blog/?p=163
they really didnt 'not to', but too many 'expensive' things add up.

and actually, all included/required files are added to an internal array (theres a function to return it), i guess the _once's have to loop that array and do strcmp's, which would add up

Answer (score 7):

A better way to do things is to use an object-oriented approach and use [__autoload()](http://www.php.net/__autoload).

Comment: but the very first example in the autoloading objects page you linked to uses require_once

Comment: I don't buy this. There are MANY situations in which OO does not fit as appropriately as other paradigms, so you shouldn't force it just to gain whatever tiny advantages there may be with __autoload().

Comment: you'd think that autoload would actually take longer than *_once (assuming that you're only require'ing what you need).

Comment: No it is not, at least not definitely, Autoload still needs to be included somehow and it is a last resort for PHP before error fail - so in reality PHP actually perform potentionally unnecessary checks through all places that would apply to include/require and **AFTER THAT** it would call autoload (if any defined)... 
PS: `__autoload()` is discouraged and it may be deprecated in the future, you should use `spl_autoload_register(...)` these days... PS2: don't get me wrong, I do use autoload functionality sometimes ;)

Answer (score 6):

The `*_once()` functions [stat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_(system_call)) every parent directory to ensure the file you're including isn't the same as one that's already been included. That's part of the reason for the slowdown.

I recommend using a tool like [Siege](http://www.joedog.org/JoeDog/Siege) for benchmarking. You can try all the suggested methodologies and compare response times.

More on `require_once()` is at [Tech Your Universe](https://web.archive.org/web/20110713073725/http://www.techyouruniverse.com/software/php-performance-tip-require-versus-require_once) *<sup>[url](http://www.techyouruniverse.com/software/php-performance-tip-require-versus-require_once)</sup>*.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the article.  require_once() is a good safety belt over double-including files, and we'll continue to use it, but being able to make it clean is nice.

Answer (score 6):

The PEAR2 wiki (when it existed) used to list [good reasons for abandoning *all* the require/include directives in favor of autoload](http://web.archive.org/web/20090219000012/http://wiki.pear.php.net/index.php/PEAR2_Standards#Introduction)ing, at least for library code. These tie you down to rigid directory structures when alternative packaging models like [phar](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.phar.php) are on the horizon.

Update: As the web archived version of the wiki is eye-gougingly ugly, I've copied the most compelling reasons below:

> - include_path is required in order to use a (PEAR) package. This makes it difficult to bundle a PEAR package within another application with its
>     own include_path, to create a single file containing needed classes,
>     to move a PEAR package to a phar archive without extensive source code
>     modification.
> - when top-level require_once is mixed with conditional require_once, this can result in code that is uncacheable by opcode caches such as
>     APC, which will be bundled with PHP 6.
> - relative require_once requires that include_path already be set up to the correct value, making it impossible to use a package without
>     proper include_path

Answer (score 6):

It's not using the function that is bad. It's an incorrect understanding of how and when to use it, in an overall code base. I'll just add a bit more context to that possibly misunderstood notion:

People shouldn't think that require_once is a slow function. You have to include your code one way or another. `require_once()` vs. `require()`'s speed isn't the issue. It's about the performance hindering caveats that may results for using it blindly. If used broadly without consideration for context, it can lead to huge memory waste or wasteful code.

What I have seen that's really bad, is when huge monolithic frameworks use `require_once()` in all the wrong ways, especially in a complex object-oriented (OO) environment.

Take the example of using `require_once()` at the top of every class as seen in many libraries:

```
require_once("includes/usergroups.php");
require_once("includes/permissions.php");
require_once("includes/revisions.php");
class User{
  // User functions
}
```

So the `User` class is designed to use all three other classes. Fair enough!

But now what if a visitor is browsing the site and not even logged in and the framework loads: `require_once("includes/user.php");` for every single request.

It's including 1+3 *unnecessary* classes it won't ever use during that particular request. This is how bloated frameworks end up using 40 MB per request as opposed to 5 MB or less.

---

The other ways it can be misused, is when a class is re-used by many others!
Say you have about 50 classes that use `helper` functions. To make sure `helpers` are available for those classes when they are loaded, you get:

```
require_once("includes/helpers.php");
class MyClass{
  // Helper::functions(); // etc..
}
```

There is nothing wrong here per se. However if one page request happens to include 15 similar classes. You are running `require_once` 15 times, or for a nice visual:

```
require_once("includes/helpers.php");
require_once("includes/helpers.php");
require_once("includes/helpers.php");
require_once("includes/helpers.php");
require_once("includes/helpers.php");
require_once("includes/helpers.php");
require_once("includes/helpers.php");
require_once("includes/helpers.php");
require_once("includes/helpers.php");
require_once("includes/helpers.php");
require_once("includes/helpers.php");
require_once("includes/helpers.php");
require_once("includes/helpers.php");
require_once("includes/helpers.php");
require_once("includes/helpers.php");
```

The use of require_once() technically affects performance for running that function 14 times, on top of having to parse those unnecessary lines. With just 10 other highly used classes with that similar problem, it could account for 100+ lines of such rather pointless repetitive code.

With that, it's probably worth using `require("includes/helpers.php");` at the bootstrap of your application or framework, instead. But since everything is relative, *it all depends* if the weight versus usage frequency of the `helpers` class is worth saving 15-100 lines of `require_once()`. But if the probability of not using the `helpers` file on any given request is none, then `require` should definitely be in your main class instead. Having `require_once` in each class separately becomes a waste of resources.

---

The `require_once` function is useful when necessary, but it shouldn't be regarded as a monolithic solution to use everywhere for loading all classes.

Comment: "The use of require_once() technically affects performance for running that function 14 times" - can you share more details about this? Some lines above, you wrote that  the speed is not an issue, so which kind of performance impact does this affect?

Comment: @NicoHaase With OPCache now being included as default in current PHP version, the speed cost of the `require_once()` function itself is negligible, as  [demonstrated for `include()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29071889/1647538). Any repeat intermediate bytecode still has to interpreted by the runtime engine. But there is no function penalty to be worry about unless OPCache is disabled... There are however  performance costs in terms of compiled memory usage to be mindful about, if overused.

Answer (score 3):

Even if `require_once` and `include_once` *are* slower than `require` and `include` (or whatever alternatives might exist), we're talking about the smallest level of micro-optimization here. Your time is much better spent optimizing that poorly written loop or database query than worrying about something like `require_once`.

Now, one could make an argument saying that `require_once` allows for poor coding practices because you don't need to pay attention to keeping your includes clean and organized, but that has nothing to do with the function *itself* and especially not its speed.

Obviously, autoloading is better for the sake of code cleanliness and ease of maintenance, but I want to make it clear that this has nothing to do with *speed*.

Answer (score 0):

You test, using include, oli's alternative and __autoload(); and test it with [something like APC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_PHP_Cache#Alternative_PHP_Cache) installed.

I doubt using constant will speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is slightly more expensive than plain ol' require(). I think the point is if you can keep your code organized enough to not duplicate includes, don't use the *_once() functions, as it will save you some cycles.

But using the _once() functions isn't going to kill your application. Basically, just **don't use it as an excuse to not have to organize your includes**. In some cases, using it is still unavoidable, and it's not a big deal.

Answer (score -3):

I think in PEAR documentation, there is a recommendation for require, require_once, include and include_once. I do follow that guideline. Your application would be more clear.

Comment: Some references would be in order.

Answer (score -3):

It has nothing to do with speed. It's about failing gracefully.

If require_once() fails, your script is done. Nothing else is processed. If you use include_once() the rest of your script will try to continue to render, so your users potentially would be none-the-wiser to something that has failed in your script.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can actually hook in an error handler or on shutdown handler to give the user a nice error page (although people rarely do). As a developer, I would much rather things error immediately.

Comment: Or, as the case may be, *not* failing gracefully - if some vital file isn't require()'d properly, it's a good idea just to give up and halt. But that's require vs include, whereas I think the question is more focused on require vs require_once.

Answer (score -4):

My personal opinion is that the usage of require_once (or include_once) is bad practice because require_once checks for you if you already included that file and suppress errors of double included files resulting in fatal errors (like duplicate declaration of functions/classes/etc.).

You should know if you need to include a file.