# How to include a class in PHP

Tags: php, include, require

I have file `index.php`, and I want to include file `class.twitter.php` inside it. How can I do this?

Hopefully, when I put the below code in index.php it will work.

```
$t = new twitter();
$t->username = 'user';
$t->password = 'password';

$data = $t->publicTimeline();
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: I fixed your code sample - note that you can just type the code as it is instead of using HTML entities.

Comment: I don't understand how this question can be marked off topic ?
It is a clear coding question, it contains code and the question is very easy to understand and to answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14350866/6521116

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your code should be something like

```
require_once('class.twitter.php');

$t = new twitter;
$t->username = 'user';
$t->password = 'password';

$data = $t->publicTimeline();
```

Answer (score 18):

### Include a class example with the `use` keyword from Command Line Interface:

PHP Namespaces don't work on the commandline unless you also include or require the php file.  When the php file is sitting in the webspace where it is interpreted by the php daemon then you don't need the require line.  All you need is the 'use' line.

1. Create a new directory `/home/el/bin`
2. Make a new file called `namespace_example.php` and put this code in there:

   ```
   <?php
       require '/home/el/bin/mylib.php';
       use foobarwhatever\dingdong\penguinclass;

       $mypenguin = new penguinclass();
       echo $mypenguin->msg();
   ?>
   ```
3. Make another file called `mylib.php` and put this code in there:

   ```
   <?php
   namespace foobarwhatever\dingdong;
   class penguinclass 
   {
       public function msg() {
           return "It's a beautiful day chris, come out and play! " . 
                  "NO!  *SLAM!*  taka taka taka taka."; 
       }   
   }
   ?>
   ```
4. Run it from commandline like this:

   ```
   el@apollo:~/bin$ php namespace_example.php
   ```
5. Which prints:

   ```
   It's a beautiful day chris, come out and play!
   NO!  *SLAM!*  taka taka taka taka
   ```

See notes on this in the comments here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Answer (score 15):

You can use either of the following:

```
include "class.twitter.php";
```

or

```
require "class.twitter.php";
```

Using `require` (or `require_once` if you want to ensure the class is only loaded once during execution) will cause a fatal error to be raised if the file doesn't exist, whereas `include` will only raise a warning.  See http://php.net/require and http://php.net/include for more details

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you also take a look at [__autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).
This will clean up the code of requires and includes.

Comment: A code example would be nice.

Comment: @PeterMortensen  You can see examples here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php One thing  that php does really well is documentation

Comment: @AntonioCS If you look at the sheer mass of often times very useful and even crucial comments in the PHP docs you might want to ponder over the quality of documentation PHP delivers.

Answer (score 4):

1. `require('/yourpath/yourphp.php');`

   http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php
2. `require_once('/yourpath/yourphp.php');`

   http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php
3. `include '/yourpath/yourphp.php';`

   http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php
4. `use \Yourapp\Yourname`

   http://php.net/manual/fa/language.namespaces.importing.php

Notes:

Avoid using require_once because it is slow: [Why is require_once so bad to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186338/why-is-require-once-so-bad-to-use)

Answer (score 1):

Check:
http://www.php.net/require
and
http://www.php.net/include