# How to avoid writing include_once() in file again and again for including different class?

Tags: php, include

I have code structure in which I have class file, template file and controller file. And in every conroller file I have to call atleast 6 include_once(); How to avoid writing include_once() in file again and again for including different class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at PHP 5's [autoloading mechanism](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

It takes care of including the necessary files *when the class is used*.

In addition to saving you tons of include statements, only includes actually used in the current context will be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

include_once is handy, no doubt,
but handy always pay a price
check [discussion about include_once/require_once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186338/why-is-require-once-so-bad-to-use)

I suggest you **Should check before doing any include/include_once**,
and wrap it as function

such as

```
function include_more($classes)
{
  foreach ($classes as $class)
  {
    if (!class_exists($class)) 
    {
      include $class.'.class';
    }
  }
}
```

In your controller, implement

```
include_more( array('Database', 'View', ...);
```