# PHP Optimization __autoload/require_once

Tags: php, optimization

I just did a bit of Research about Optimizing my PHP Code.
In my Code Im using this function to include all classes I require:

```
function __autoload($class_name){
   require_once "system/classes/".strtolower($class_name).".php";
}
```

Now I have read, that Magic functions or whatever `__autoload` is called should be avoided.

And also that `require_once` is really slow commpared to a simple `include`.
I wondered if there is an alternativ to `__autoload` or whats the best way to modyfy this function. 
Is there a Speed Difference between `require` and `include`?

Thaks in advance for your suggestions!

EDIT: Does iit also make sens to Cache or precompile the classes?

Comment: http://php.net/spl-autoload-register

Comment: There is no significant performance difference between include() and require(). If you're only using one autoload method, then the older `__autoload` is sufficient. `spl_autoload_register` is only a requirement to combine multiple autoloaders.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php spl\_autoload\_register vs \_\_autoload?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6894538)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP include vs include\_once (speed)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4326435)

Comment: Re your edit.... if you're using a modern version of PHP with OpCache, it already does cache the compiled bytecode for your files

Comment: Didnt know that @MarkBaker Thank! I dont Need `spl_autoload_register`

Comment: A big benefit of spl_autoload_register is that it only loads the individual files for your classes if and when they are actually needed, that can help save your PHP memory as well