# Keep navigation bar an all pages

Tags: php, html, navigation

hope you fine and well,

i have a navigation bar like this :

```
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a onclick="load_home()"href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

how i can show this bar in all my html and php pages !

regards.

Comment: You can use an include .. for this ..

Comment: is `load_home()` a javascript or php function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the render code in a **my_navbar.php**

```
         echo '<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a onclick="load_home()"href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>';
```

and then in all php file you need the navbar put

```
<?php
 include_once "my_navbar.php"; // this will include a.php

?>
```

Use include_once for avoiding multiple include

Comment: thanks dear , but to use this i have to change all my files to php ! true ?! how i can do similar concept but with keeping html files ?!

Comment: I think the php solution is the  more simple but you can add code with jquery .. or  html link  ..

Comment: Yes .. i know it this solution but you can explore are several .. depend on your context.. .. another good "way" with php is use framework .. they are all good solution for this kind of need .. anyway if the problem is strictly related to navbar .. try firts the link solution ... is more HTML complaint.. then i suggest the jquery solution .. i hope this suggestions are  useful for you ..

Comment: thanks dear i will tests all given solutions, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on scaisEdge's comment, here's how you can do this in an include.

In nav.php (name it however you want):

```
<?php
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li>
                  <a onclick="load_home()"href="#">About</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Services</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
?>
```

Then where you want the navigation:

```
<?php include('nav.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [include()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), i.e.:

**navigation.php**

```
<?php
echo <<< EOF
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li>
         <a onclick="load_home()"href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="#">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
EOF;
```

**anotherfile.php**

```
<?php
include("navigation.php");
//the rest of the code...
```

---

[include vs include_once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4326785/797495):

> The `include_once` and `require_once` functions are **slower** than `include`
>   and `require`, simply because they **keep track** of the files that have
>   already been included, to avoid including them more than once.