# When does the class load, when including the file or when initiating the class?

Tags: php, class

IF i include a file into another file. i.e foo.php contains the class "foo", with several methods. At what point does php load the classes into memory, on the include or on the class 
initiation.

here: `include ('foo.php');`

or here: `$foo = new foo();`

For example: If i were to include 50 files that all contain unique classes but only call 1 of those classes what would happen in terms of memory usage? speed? overall - please explain the badness of that action.

Comment: try for yourself: http://php.net/memory_get_usage

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890825/cost-of-include-in-php

Comment: All you have to do, is read the first sentence in [*the manual*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Answer (score 2):

When you `include` a file, all that PHP does is parse that file, and irrespective of whether it contains a class definition, procedural lines, or entirely commented out code, it `includes` those lines into the current file you have, and then `evaluates` them. In other words, looks for syntax errors, if the lines are executable - executes them. If you have 50 class files all "included", once the include process is complete, it becomes similar to if you had a single file with all 50 classes defined in it. The behavior for instantiating a single class or multiple classes, then becomes the same. The only difference in overhead would come for the individual evaluation, and inclusion of those 50 files.

If you do have a use case of lots of files with different classes, and only need to include them based on the ones that you might load, check out the autoload functionality in PHP:

```
<?php
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
}

$first = new FirstClass();
$second = new SecondClass(); 
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: The overhead would be limited if you specified what files needed to be included and limited to just them.  Thank you, that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, and also PHP provides special autoload functionality for including class based files for initialization.