# sending data into another php files cost

Tags: php

I want to know if sending huge records to another php file functions cost more than to create functions in a current php file?

For example, in my current php file **upload.php**  I have two type of arrays:
`$result1` and `$result2`, each with  lots of records and I want to upload these records to my database with functions name `upload_type1` and `upload__type2`.

Is it better to:

1. Create these functions in my current file?
2. Create these functions in a different file like **databaseupload.php**, and then send the `$result` array to **databaseupload.php** to have cleaner code?

Does the second way cost more?

I want to know what way is the better programming way. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could simply pass your vars by [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) to the processing function

Comment: my question is about time cost is passing data through files take cost or not ?

Comment: Tell us more details. How would you transfer the data between the 2 PHP files? BTW, nothing is faster than using a local var (or a reference), in the same PHP file or in 2 PHP files (using include / require)

Comment: is sending a data to a function (function($data)) that is in other php file and included in ur currnet file send a copy of ur data to second php file and duplicate ur data? if its true does it cost so much ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the performance cost of "include" in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890825/whats-the-performance-cost-of-include-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally its so subjective but for two simple function there is not much difference to implement them inside or separate them in different file if you are concerning about overhead in your app. you can find more details and statistic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890825/whats-the-performance-cost-of-include-in-php).

But having clean code is much more effective, I believe.

You'd better follow famous design patterns and [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) to know where and how create classes and functions.

Comment: is sending a data to a function (function($data)) that is in other php file and included in ur currnet file send a copy of ur data to second php file and duplicate ur data? if its true does it cost so much ?

Comment: @MR.masoud when it comes to passing data to a function, as long as you have access to that function, there is no difference where is located that function physically because that function has already loaded in memory.