# PHP include VS loop

Tags: php, loops, include

**Using LOOP**

```
for ($i=0; $i < 1000; $i++) 
{ 
    echo "<li>content $i</li>";
}
```

**Using INCLUDE**

```
include("file.php");
```

the **file.php** contains same content as the loop but it is hard coded or static.

I've tried to run those two different codes on local host and monitor their response time. I can't decide which one to choose because the response time changes over time, some times the LOOP is faster but some time the INCLUDE is faster.

I want to ask your recommendation on which one is best to use.

Comment: If you can't measure the difference consistently, then do you really believe that it matters for performance?

Comment: But if the included file contains the same code as the loop, then you're not even comparing anything different

Comment: @MarkBaker I updated my question. The file.php contains same content as the loop but it is hard coded or static.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, directly using the loop would be faster. The reason is that when you use the include function, the php compiler has to make a call to include function and then fetch the file. Although the cost of include function is negligible, ( nearly 100 include will cause a lag of 4 milliseconds , but that's not something to worry about).

In the end it all comes down to individual preferences, as this loop might be having a lot of lines of code in the real world and you might want to keep it in a different file for structural purposes

Read This
[What's the performance cost of "include" in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890825/whats-the-performance-cost-of-include-in-php)