# try catch a failed include

Tags: php, include, try-catch

This is  a simple question one hour of Googling do not seem to solve. How do you catch a failed include in PHP? For the following code:

```
try {
    include_once 'mythical_file';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    exit('Fatal');
}

echo '?';
```

With mythical_file not existing, I get the output '?'. I know PHP can not catch failed required because it triggers a Warning Error, but here? What is the best way to catch a failed include? For example, the following works:

```
(include_once 'unicorn') or exit('!');
```

but it does not trigger an exception so I cannot retrieve file, line and stack context.

Comment: You may want to look into [register_shutdown_function()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) in combination with [error_get_last()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php). Should be able to retrieve file, line, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `require_once` instead of `include_once`

Comment: Well I guess I will have to close the ticket because apparently it works on some of my virtual hosts and others not (using require will trigger a 500 error). Thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: @fabjoa, @Gaurav - we don't have "tickets" here, so there's nothing closable.

Answer (score 1):

[include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) and [include_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) trigger **warning (E_WARNING)**, [require](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) and [require_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) trigger **error (E_COMPILE_ERROR)**. So you should use `require` or `require_once`.

php.net quote:

> "require() is identical to include()
>   except upon failure it will also
>   produce a **fatal** E_COMPILE_ERROR level
>   error. In other words, it will halt
>   the script whereas include() only
>   emits a warning (E_WARNING) which
>   allows the script to continue. "

Comment: Do not use `_once` unless you absolutely have to because it affects performance a bit.

Comment: @tntu can you explain?  It was my understanding that using require or include when the file is already included is a bigger waste of resources than using _once.  Thank you!

Comment: @billrichards If you write good code you should never encounter the situation where you include the same file twice. The explanation what the difference in performance is is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186338/why-is-require-once-so-bad-to-use

Comment: @tntu thanks for the info and the link!  someday when i start writing good code, i'll be able to stop using require_once and include_once