# using 'global' in php

Tags: php, global, scoping

I'm in learning mode here, very new to PHP, so I'm working with a code sample.
Please forgive my use of 'global' here, but I want to understand php variable scoping.

**Here is myGlobals.php:**

```
<?php 
     global $db_server;
   // other code not shown
?>
```

**Here is connectToDb.php:**

```
<?php
      require_once 'myGlobals.php';

      // no declared functions in this file, all inline code
      $db_server = mysql_connect(.....);
      mysql_select_db( "theDatabase", $db_server);
?>
```

**Here is addDbRecords.php:**

```
<?php
       require_once 'myGlobals.php';

       // other inline code.....
       doAddDeleteRecord($db_server);

function doAddDeleteRecord($db_server)
{
  //global $db_server;

  if( !mysql_query($query, $db_server))
   {
         // handle the error...
   }
 }
?>
```

**Here is index.php:**

```
<?php
      require_once 'myGlobals.php';
      require_once 'connectToDb.php';
      require_once 'addDbRecords.php';

     // this is simplified, just trying to show that everything in inline code
 ?>
```

Here is the problem.  When I call `doAddDeleteRecord($db_server)` inside the file addDbRecords.php 
above, `$db_server` is not valid -- it is null -- when I call `mysql_query(.., $db_server, ...)`  -- this is the error message:

> "Warning: mysql_query() expects
>   parameter 2 to be resource, null given
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\addDbRecords.php on
>   line 29"

So I tried using the 'global' declaration inside `doAddDeleteRecord()` (commented out above) -- no change.
The `mysql_query(...)` still fails with a NULL value for `$db_server`.

I know the `mysql_connect(....)` works because other code pulls all my records out of my database successfully (using a SELECT) and the existing records get displayed correctly in the browser.

So in my opinion, the fact that `$db_server` is declared with 'global' should mean that the scope of `$db_server` is such that once `mysql_connect(...)` is called -- at file scope in all my files, `$db_server` will be a valid connection to my database.

I'm only trying to learn about **php scoping**, not OOAD or anything else (for now).  Why is `$db_server()` null here?

Comment: never use require_once. use require

Comment: @yes123: Why's that? Most of the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186338/why-is-require-once-so-bad-to-use) seem to claim that that's a myth.

Comment: If you still use the old mysql_ interface functions, you don't have to pass the connection handle around. If there is only one opened, it is used implicitly. (Unless you pass a null value.)

Comment: @yes123 Uh, that's horrid advice, especially if there are function declarations in the required file.

Comment: @yes123: Why would you not recommend require_once over require?

Comment: @require_once: It might indeed be a cause of the troubles here, because the `myglobals.php` script is really just loaded **once**, where OP might have intended it to be included multiple times. (The general disadvisal makes no sense however.)

Comment: using `global $db_server;`  inside `doAddDeleteRecord()` should work correctly.  Are you absolutely sure you don't also have `$db_server` referenced in that file anywhere, like `global$ dbserver;`?  This would redeclare it as NULL.

Comment: @mario: no it won't. The global only needs to be defined once. This won't cause these sorts of problems.

Comment: @Chris: I get that. It needs no redeclarations. But if the myglobals script was to be used for localizing the variable in multiple spots (which is not senseful), then the _once call is what made it not work out.

Comment: It looks like it ought to work... Are you sure there isn't something else causing `mysql_connect()` to fail? You don't *need* to run `global $db_server;` multiple times, so I too have to disagree with `yes123` here: You should always use the `_require()` variations **unless** the file contains only procedural code and is intended to be run multiple times.

Comment: @mario: except that the OP isn't using `include[_once]` inside of a function. The OP is including it at the top of each file, which no matter how you cut it would still require the use of the `global` modifier to use those variables within functions.

Comment: In hindsight, I don't think you need `global` at all in your code. You're always referencing the variable from the global scope.

Comment: @Chris: All examples are shortened. And that the commands occur at the top is not indicative for execution in the global scope (scripts might itself be included from within functions). Either way using a plain `global` var declaration is the better alternative to the `myGlobals` include.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, you have:

```
<?php 
     global $db_server;
   // other code not shown
?>
```

and you include this where needed:

```
require_once 'myGlobals.php';
// other inline code.....
doAddDeleteRecord($db_server);
```

The problem is that if you already included 'myGlobals.php' elsewhere, it won't be included here. So you can't guarantee that the global will be brought into scope.

Instead, write:

```
require 'myGlobals.php';
// other inline code.....
doAddDeleteRecord($db_server);
```

Or take the much better approach of just:

```
// other inline code.....
doAddDeleteRecord($GLOBALS['db_server']);
```

Comment: +1 you use `global` inside a function to tell PHP you want to use a globally scoped variable instead of creating a privately scoped variable that is only visible in the function.

Comment: I disagree, I have a four-file set-up working right now and they **all** use `require_once()`. The very first time you execute the statement `global $db_server` is sufficient.

Comment: @Darien: Only if you always include the file at the global scope.

Comment: Actually the problem with my answer is that the `global` isn't required _at all_ in any of his files.

Comment: That's a problem too, but what I mean is that the side-effects of `global $foo;`, when (pointlessly) done in global scope, are also global... as long as it has been included once, early enough, you never need to include it again. It's the same as if you had defined a function or class in global scope.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a concern with scope hiding; that is, you're using the same name ($db_server) for the global and for the function local variable.  The function local scope hides the global variable name.  If you have a global, you don't need to pass it to your function; if you do, don't use the same name for it.

Comment: I changed the variable name to "function doAddDeleteRecord($db_server_global_scope)" and used db_server_global_scope in the call to mysql_query(.., $db_server_global_scope, ...) -- no change.   Just FYI, I did not use 'global' anywhere before, only added it to try to fix this.  If I remove 'global' everywhere it's still the same problem.  Note: the call to doAddDeleteRecord($db_server_global_scope) that is failing is when my 'add record' form posts back to the file -- could the fact that I'm re-entering the code due to a POST somehow make the db_server null?