# PHP: Cannot restrict access to page

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have header.php which contains init.php which starts the session and further contains all the functions and classes for database queries.
I have header.php included in every file because it contains the menu. The menu is updated if the user is logged in or not. This works fine.

But my problem is: when including header.php on another page, I am unable to further include init.php as it has already been included in header.php, and so I cannot call any functions in those pages which I certainly need to.

For example, there is a page called new.php (which also contains header.php) where admin can add new entries into the db; and I want it accessible only to the admin. So what I wanted to do was to check if the rank of the user is 2 otherwise redirect. So to retrieve the rank of the user I need to use the function inside a class in init.php. To do that, if I place the logic code below header.php (in new.php) because only then I will be able to access the objects of init.php, I am unable to use the header() function because headers are already sent. And if I try to declare it above header.php (in new.php) by including the init.php file again, it gives me: multiple declaration error of class is not allowed.

Here is the piece of code:

header.php

```
<?php
      require 'core/init.php';
      if($general->logged_in()){
        $user = $user->userdata($_SESSION['uid']);
        $username = $user['username'];
        $rank = $user['rank'];
      }
?>
<!--Menu bar html below-->
```

new.php

```
<?php  
    include 'includes/header.php';
    <!--Check for the rank and redirect if invalid-->
?>
```

Comment: `<!--Check for the rank and redirect if invalid-->` This is an html comment, which can be viewed by anyone looking into the source. It's not the best practice revealing personal business. Use `/* my comment */` instead

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`require_once`](http://php.net/require-once). It may be the answer to your problems.

Comment: I tried to use it but no luck. It still gets included and there is no other way it cannot get included twice even by using require_once in both files.

Comment: Hmm... it looks like your include file is... defining variables? That's not good. Consider using a static method, like `Core::logged_in()` instead - that way you don't have to pass references around and can get it from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think `include_once` you can read about it [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) and from [this other good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186338/why-is-require-once-so-bad-to-use) you can learn what is difference when it comes to speed and performance in the server, and which one is more expensive to execute.
also this wrong

```
<!--Check for the rank and redirect if invalid-->
```

comments in php are like this

```
 /* Check for the rank and redirect if invalid */
```