# Determine files modified by process

Tags: linux, unix

I'm writing a program to be run from the Linux user space which spawns another process. How can it determine which files were modified by the spawned process after it completes?

Comment: Are you writing the spawned pgm or is it just some existing pgm over which you have no control and just using system() or the like?

Comment: Not writing the spawned program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call it under [strace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174942/how-to-use-strace) and parse the output you care about.

Comment: Didn't know about this program - thanks for the hint! Shows a lot more than wrapping fopen() but still doesn't catch writes from g++.

Comment: @balor: What are you doing with g++ that you don't know what files it writes?  Normally it only modifies a single file and you can give the name on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

[Inject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection) your own replacement for `fopen(3)` that records the names and modes.

Comment: I think the proper jargon here is "library interposition". It's not a bad idea but doesn't seem to work for some reason on the program that I'm trying to monitor (g++). I'm only seeing accesses to files in /tmp.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe g++ itself spawns other processes? Than "strace -fF -efile program" plus some filtering will probably help you.