# using file descriptor from system call in C

Tags: c++, c, linux, assembly, linux-kernel

hey I would like to open and read a file using system calls
and print the data in it letter by letter
I have the function system_call in an assembly file
and I want to "save" to pointer to the file descriptor  from the system_call(SYS_OPEN
to use it. the purpose is not using #include directory

my code is

```
system_call(SYS_OPEN,argv[2],0,)
```

where argv[2] = "a.txt"
SYS_OPEN = 5
and the 4th param should be permission, and i dont know what to write there

after "saving" it to pointer I would like to read and print like this

```
while(system_call(SYS_READ,STDIN, input_char , 1)>0)
  {
  system_call(SYS_WRITE,STDOUT,input_char, 1);
  }
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write code to do this using library functions (i.e. `open`(2), `read`(2)), then run the program under `strace` to see the function calls it makes and parameters it uses, then replicate that in your own code....

Comment: I didnt use strace before .. how can i use it? you have maby a like for a manual?

Comment: @Kika see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174942/how-to-use-strace

Answer (score 2):

That's a list of system calls (may be a but outdated, but will work for you) http://asm.sourceforge.net/syscall.html .You can check an implementation details and usage of system_call in appropriate linux kernel sources for sys_open, sys_read, sys_write etc..

Answer (score 0):

Got it by using int as pointer to file:

```
char input_char[1];
int file = system_call(SYS_OPEN,argv[j],0,0777);

while(system_call(SYS_READ,file, input_char , 1) >0 )
  {
  system_call(SYS_WRITE,STDOUT,input_char, 1);
  }
```

Thanks you for your comments and help