# See output of a background process

Tags: c, linux, process, background, stdout

I'm testing on Debian a routing algorithm wrote in C. In algorithm source file i set a flag to 1 to enable the printing of routing decisions on stdout. Problem is: the process that runs this file is a background process. How can i see stdout?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the below line to check what your process is doing.

```
$ strace -p $!
```

`$!` gives the process ID of the last background process. Remember to run the above line in same console as the background process.

Comment: What if the original console is disconnected and I have to login on from another console ?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have the process you want to listen to already up and running, and you don't want to stop and rerun it with a redirection as Laszlo suggests: you can use `strace` to listen to it - [How should strace be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174942/how-to-use-strace)

Basically it can track all system call activities, but that includes printing

Add `-p <pid>` to attach it to your desired process. Add `-e write` to filter most of the stuff and get only the output writes

For e.g.:

```
> grep somestring . -R >& /dev/null &
  [2] 8093
> strace -p 8093 -e write
...here goes the output...
```

Answer (score 1):

You redirect the output of your program into a file, and then you can watch the output in that file.