# Monitor stat calls for I/O in php scripts

Tags: php, performance, stat, in-memory, opcache

For a side project I aim to run my php application completely in memory, using PHP 5.5+ OpCache and Redis as persistent storage. Now I am using `include` and `file_exists()` as the two calls which possibly perform a stat call.

With a scripts like [ocp.php](https://gist.github.com/ck-on/4959032) I can check the files hits/misses. I wonder however, how could I check whether there are *any* stat calls made (like, `file_exists()` too) and when & where they are made?

I would like to profile my deployment this way to tune any possible php configuration to run the app completely in memory.

Comment: Are you already using Xdebug? If not, maybe the Profiler (docs: http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) can help you out.

Comment: I'm posting this as a comment, not an answer because it's probably not exactly the solution you want, but you could `strace` the script, maybe:  `strace -etrace=stat64 PID_HERE` or `strace PID_HERE 2>&1 | grep stat`

Comment: @Bjorn yes I have the profiler. Haven't thought about it (as it does not show any system calls) but it notified my that Slim was calling `is_file()` twice in `Slim\View::render()`!

Comment: @Kevin thanks for the response! Now using strace with `strace -tfp {PID} 2>&1` like I found in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24309424/434223) which gives me quite good results. If I went through all the output, I will post some more info here with interesting results!