# file_exists returns false after several checks on same file

Tags: php, apache, file-exists

I got a weird issue I'm not able to fix.

I got the following code which gets called several times from different requests

```
if(file_exists("settings.ini"))
{
    $ini = parse_ini_file("settings.ini", true);

    // do things with $ini
}
```

as you can see I'm just parsing the ini file and this is the only place in my whole code where I'm touching this file. However sometimes the `file_exists`-call returns  `false` (never the first time) even if I call `clearstatcache` before. The file permission is set to `0755`.

Can anyone explain me why this is happening and how to avoid that?

**Update**

I've noticed that this is only happening if I'm using Firefox (V50). Chrome and IE working fine.

Comment: You're calling it from different folders?

Comment: Assuming you're using Linux, you could try to use [strace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174942/how-should-strace-be-used) to see what files are being opened and when.

Comment: @MarkBaker nope always same folder. The *.php and *.ini in the same folder. Absolute/relative makes no difference here, already tried

Comment: Append an `else fopen("settings.ini", "r");` Perhaps the error message tells you the tried path.

Comment: @Holger Yip, got `fopen(settings.ini): failed to open stream: No such file or directory` however the file is there...

Comment: Hmm, you could output getCWD() at this point.

Comment: @Holger Good one thank you. It seems i got an error before so the server redirects to Error 500 before calling my function so i'm in the wrong directory ;)