# Socket hangup due to wrong handling of promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

I have script to move data from one platform to another. The source db allows only 100 records to be fetched in a single request. So I created a routine to fetch by batches of 100 which works fine I guess.

Now I try to process each records of 100 and do the necessary transformations (which involves axios call to get certain data) and create a record in firebase firestore.
Now when I run this migration in firebase express node, I get socket hang up ECONNRESET.

I know this is caused by wrong handling of promises.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
import { scrollByBatches } from "../helpers/migrations/apiScroll";
import { createServiceLocation } from "../helpers/locations";

const mapServiceLocationData = async (serviceLocation: any, env: string) => {
  try {
    const migratedServiceLocation: any = {
      isMigrated: true,
      id: serviceLocation._id,
    };


    if (serviceLocation.list?.length) {
      await Promise.all(serviceLocation.ids.map(async (id: string) => {
        const { data } = await dbEndPoint.priceMultiplier({ id });  // error says socket hangup on this call
        let multiplierUnit;
        let serviceType;
        if (data.response._id) {
          multiplierUnit = data.response;
          const result = await dbEndPoint.serviceType({ id: multiplierUnit.service_custom_service_type }); // error says socket hangup on this call
          if (result.data.response._id) {
            serviceType = result.data.response.type_text;
            migratedServiceLocation.logs = [...multiplierUnit.history_list_text, ...migratedServiceLocation.logs];
          }
        }
      }));
    }

    await createServiceLocation(migratedServiceLocation); // create record in destination db
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error serviceLocation: ", serviceLocation._id, JSON.stringify(error));
  }
  return null; // is this even necessary?
};

export const up = async () => {
  try {
    // get 100 docs from source db => process it.. => fetch next 100 => so on...
    await scrollByBatches(dbEndPoint.serviceLocation, async (serviceLocations: any) => {
      await Promise.all(
          serviceLocations.map(async (serviceLocation: any) => {
            await mapServiceLocationData(serviceLocation);
          })
      );
    }, 100);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error", JSON.stringify(error));
  }
  return null; // is this even necessary?
};
```

The error I get in firebase functions console is:
[image: Socket hangup error firebase console]

For clarity on how the fetch by batches looks like:

```
const iterateInBatches = async (endPoint: any, limit: number, cursor: number, callback: any, resolve: any, reject: any) => {
  try {
    const result = await endPoint({ limit, cursor });
    const { results, remaining }: any = result.data.response;

    if (remaining >= 0) {
      await callback(results);
    }
    if ((remaining)) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        iterateInBatches(endPoint, limit, (cursor + limit), callback, resolve, reject);
      }, 1000); // wait a second
    } else {
      resolve();
    }
  } catch (err) {
    reject(err);
  }
};

export const scrollByBatches = async (endPoint: any, callback: any, limit: number, cursor: number = 0) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    iterateInBatches(endPoint, limit, cursor, callback, resolve, reject);
  });
};
```

What am I doing wrong? I have added comments in the code sections for readability.

Thanks.

Comment: I left that. Nothing seemed to work.

Comment: I did a work around the task.. Instead of computing and handling promises which were failing only in the cloud, in emulator everything worked fine. So what I did was did all the stuff in the emulator and made an endpoint in cloud only to create record passed as payload.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases when socket hang up gets thrown:

**When you are a client**

When you, as a client, send a request to a remote server, and receive no timely response. Your socket is ended which throws this error. You should catch this error and decide how to handle it: whether to retry the request, queue it for later, etc.

**When you are a server/proxy**

When you, as a server, perhaps a proxy server, receive a request from a client, then start acting upon it (or relay the request to the upstream server), and before you have prepared the response, the client decides to cancel/abort the request.

I would suggest a number of possibilities for you to try and test that might help you solve your issue of ECONNRESET :

- If you have access to the source database, you could try looking
  there for some logs or metrics. Perhaps you are overloading the
  service.
- Quick and dirty solution for development: Use [longjohn](https://github.com/mattinsler/longjohn), you get long
  stack traces that will contain the async operations. Clean and
  correct solution: Technically, in node, whenever you emit an 'error'
  event and no one listens to it, it will throw the error. To make it
  not throw, put a listener on it and handle it yourself. That way you
  can log the error with more information.
- You can also set NODE_DEBUG=net or use [strace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/174942/774086). They both provide you
  what the node is doing internally.
- You could restart your server and run the connection again, maybe
  your server crashed or refused the connection most likely blocked by
  the User Agent.
- You could also try running this code locally, instead of in cloud
  functions to see if there is a different result. It's possible that
  the RSG/google network is interfering somehow.
- You can also have a look at this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/request/request/issues/2047) and [stackoverflow
  thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995184/nodejs-what-does-socket-hang-up-actually-mean) to see the common fixes for the ECONNRESET issue and see if
  those help resolve the issue.